# how to make button text font bold flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this `TextButton()` which was working, and I am new to fluuter

```
TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("Don't have account?"),
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Yet when I added this argument to `styleFrom()`

```
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
```

It return this error,

```
../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_button.dart:146:22: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ButtonStyle styleFrom({
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I make the text bold preferably with an argument on `styleFrom()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fontWeight` is not a valid param for `TextButton.styleFrom`, you can modify the `TextStyle`, like this.

```dart
TextButton.styleFrom(
  foregroundColor: Colors.black,
  textStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
)
```